# propertyGrid with hastable in stringconvertor inherited class

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, propertygrid

i have hashtable in videoformates class inherited from StringConvertor class. Two functions `ConvertFrom` and `ConvertTo` override there. How iplement these two functions to show video formates as string.

```
public class VideoFormate : StringConverter
{
    private Hashtable VideoFormates;
    public VideoFormate() {
            VideoFormates = new Hashtable();
            VideoFormates[".3g2"] = "3GPP2";
            VideoFormates[".3gp"] = "3GPP";
    }
public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(VideoFormates);
    }
public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
```

class for video properties is

```
class videoProperties
{
    private string _VideoFormat;

    [TypeConverter(typeof(VideoFormate)), 
    CategoryAttribute("Video Setting"),
    DefaultValueAttribute(0), 
    DescriptionAttribute("Select a Formate from the list")]
    public string VideoFormat
    {
        get { return _VideoFormat; }
        set { _VideoFormat = value; }
    }

}
```

i want to display 3GPP2 as display member and .3gp2 as value member in combo box in propertyGrid.

Comment: 1) Is this .NET 1.1? 2) How the desirable conversion should look like? What value user should see - ".3g2" or "3GPP2"? What value should be contained in `videoProperties.VideoFormat`?

Comment: Thak you for asking. .NET 2, user see like "3GPP2" and value contain in `videoProperties.VideoFormat` is .3gp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the code i found the answer.

On first run, in above code, propertyGrid dropdown fill with `Hashtable` collection. `ConvertTo` method convert it into string. so it save as `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`.
when select an element from combo box it set `videoProperties.VideoFormat` as `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`. So i changed `ConvertTo` function as below.

```
public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value is DictionaryEntry)
        {
            return ((DictionaryEntry)value).Key;
        }
        else if (value != null)
        {
            return VideoFormates[value];
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
```

function check if value type is `DictionaryEntry` then it cast it and return the `key` element of `value` parameter. So combo box fill out with `key` values. when form shows `ConvertTo` function again called and second time return combo box values. then simplay return `Hashtable` value on the base of combo box value.